# Sadness - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I make many feel like mice.
Some think I'm the open.
But sometimes I am nice,
No need for doping.

You'll see what I am after,
Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"
I rarely hear laughter,
No matter what the day.

Half of this is crucial,
The other not so much.
This puzzle may be social,
Let's see who's super clutch.

Hint 1:

> The answer is stealthily hidden in the clues.

Hint 2:

> The half that is crucial is half of the riddle.

Hint 2 was a little hard, so I'll throw in a third (since I seem to have mastered giving vague enough hints).

Hint 3:

> It is "the open" on purpose.

Comment: I wonder if the "Half of this is crucial" is refering to half of the item refered, or  half of the rhyme?

Comment: @Shadow Z. Good question.

Comment: It feels like the second hint makes it even harder!

Comment: Maybe. Just don't try to apply that clue to the object, but rather to the prompt.

Comment: Anything to do with ISBN numbers?

Comment: @rand al'thor Nope. Nothing quite that concealed. With hint 1, there is a pattern that if you find it will give you the answer.

Comment: The first letter of the last word in each of the first 6 lines spells out MONDAY. Am I overthinking this?

Comment: @randal'thor The trick of the pattern is rather simple.

Comment: I'm almost there!  You'll see what "I am" after

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New answer. You are:

> Monday

I make many feel like mice.

> Monday is the start of the "rat race" that is our day-to-day jobs

Some think I'm the open.

> The open to the week. Plus another thing for later

But sometimes I am nice,
No need for doping.

> Sometimes you get Mondays off, and don't need coffee :)

You'll see what I am after,
Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"

> You see that Monday is after the weekend, which makes you say "yay"

I rarely hear laughter,
No matter what the day.

> This is part of the "non-crucial" part, but if you have a "case of the Mondays" it's being sad (hence the title of the puzzle) while you're back at work

Half of this is crucial,
The other not so much.

> The first half of the puzzle is crucial - if you take "the open" (the first letter) of each of the last words of the first 6 lines, it spells Monday! The second half is not so crucial.

This puzzle may be social,
Let's see who's super clutch.

> As evidenced here. I still think these are just referencing the difficulty of the puzzle and it requiring a group effort to solve.

Comment: Well done and great reasoning.

Comment: The hints helped quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> Space (as in outside-the-atmosphere)

I make many feel like mice.

> Space is *big*

Some think I'm the open.

> Space is fairly 'open', as in not much stuff being in it

But sometimes I am nice,

> What if space [sent us a diamond](https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/)?

No need for doping.

> I... suppose you don't need to take drugs in space?

You'll see what I am after,
Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"

> Space is cool, and we should send more stuff there. Yay!

I rarely hear laughter,

> Being devoid of nearly all atmosphere, laughter (sound) doesn't travel very well.

No matter what the day.

> Space never has an atmosphere, so it doesn't hear laughter on *any* day

Half of this is crucial,
The other not so much.

> Some things we do in space (mapping, for instance) are pretty important for modern civilization. Other things really aren't. I suppose it could be fairly half-and-half.

This puzzle may be social,
Let's see who's super clutch.

> I had to look up a couple facts written by other people. That counts as social, no?

Comment: I like it. Not what I am looking for though. There is some specific phrasing used for specific reasons.

Comment: I see a missed opportunity for putting `In space no one can hear you laugh` in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

you are

> crowd

I make many feel like mice.

> many are afraid of crowd

Some think I'm the open.

> Some people feel home with large groups

But sometimes I am nice,
No need for doping.

> some crowds are orderly

You'll see what I am after,
Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"

> Follow the crowd

I rarely hear laughter,
No matter what the day.

> This one is not fitting

Half of this is crucial,
The other not so much.

> In a group some matter rest are to show the strength

This puzzle may be social,
Let's see who's super clutch.

> Obviously groups are social

Comment: Some nice thoughts, but not what I am looking for. This doesn't fit with the laughter line.

Comment: Added that, will try to find some more appropriate item....

Comment: @AggieKidd Don't tell me it is Sadness..... you have it in your caption.......

Comment: Nope, it isn't that. I may be mean sometimes, but I'm not that mean.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> The Masters/Golf

I make many feel like mice.

> There are many great players that may make others feel small

Some think I'm the open.

> The Open - other big golf events

But sometimes I am nice,

> Sometimes you win? It can be fun to watch?

No need for doping.

> Doping doesn't have as much an effect on golf as other sports.

You'll see what I am after,

> It's after March Madness, and we will see/watch that?

Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"

> We can be happy that it's happening?

I rarely hear laughter,

> People at golf tournaments are often very quiet.

No matter what the day.

> They are quiet ever day.

Half of this is crucial,
The other not so much.

> The first stanza seems more relevant

This puzzle may be social,

> Golf can be a social game

Let's see who's super clutch.

> It helps to be clutch in golf!

Comment: Some good thoughts, but not quite. Check the hints for some additional clues.

Answer (score 3):

A wordplay idea: could it be

> ICE?

*I make many feel like mice.*

> Turn *any*thing into ice and "many" becomes "mice".

*Some think I'm the open.*

> The Open as in golf - you can play [ice golf](http://www.golf.com/photos/world-ice-golf-championship).

*But sometimes I am nice,*

> A common mishearing: e.g. if your ship is stuck in pack ice and you see a gigantic beast approaching you across the floes, you really want to know whether it's saying "I'm a nice monster" or just "I'm an ice monster."

*No need for doping.*

> ???

*You'll see what I am after,

 Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"*

> Well, if you solve the riddle to find what the OP is after, "Yay!" is certainly an appropriate response.

*I rarely hear laughter,

 No matter what the day.*

> A common metaphor: if someone has an icy demeanour, they won't laugh much.

*Half of this is crucial,

 The other not so much.*

> Half of the word "this" is "is", which is similar to "ice".

*This puzzle may be social,*

> Well, it's certainly attracted a lot of answers (and probably got on the HNQs)!

*Let's see who's super clutch.*

> I've no idea what this means.

<sub>Disclaimer: I haven't read all the OP's comments on other answers (though I have checked that nobody's already posted this as an answer), so apologies if I'm trying something that's already been excluded.</sub>

Comment: Without giving everything away, I'd go back to your comment earlier. Very nice thoughts here though.

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> A maze

I make many feel like mice.

> A parallel between men and lab mice in a maze

Some think I'm the open.

> There's a start and an end to a maze.

But sometimes I am nice,

> Mazes can be enjoyable

No need for doping.

> Testing done on lab mice doesn't need to be done on humans... yet

You'll see what I am after,
Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"

> After you finish a maze you see the path. I say "Yay" after I complete one

I rarely hear laughter, No matter what the day.

> There is usually only one person doing a PnP maze at a time. And they don't laugh while running them

Half of this is crucial,
The other not so much.

> Not sure on this one

This puzzle may be social,
Let's see who's super clutch.

> Mazes are one of the tages here on Puzzling! Super social!

Comment: Nice thoughts, but not what I'm looking for. The section you aren't sure on is very important.

Comment: I didn't include the title in my reasoning either. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

Second attempt. you are:

> death

I make many feel like mice.

> Many are afraid of it

Some think I'm the open.

> Some are ok with it, or learn to be

But sometimes I am nice,

> Some very sick/aged people find it good to have

No need for doping.

> It is soothing when it is overtaking you so all pain gone

You'll see what I am after,
Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"

> Finally most will accept it

I rarely hear laughter,
No matter what the day.

> Acceptance is ok but no one laughs/ get delighted to face it.. yippee i am gonna die

Half of this is crucial,
The other not so much.

> This piece not getting

This puzzle may be social,
Let's see who's super clutch.

> ofcourse super clutch is death no one can escape it.

Comment: I really like your thoughts, but unfortunately still not what I am looking for. The "Half of this is crucial" line is really important. But definately +1!

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> Twitter?

I make many feel like mice.

> Twitter also means the chirp sound from mice

Some think I'm the open.

> Open social media

But sometimes I am nice,
No need for doping.

> Twitting means teasing someone, a nice way to heat it up without doping

You'll see what I am after,
Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"

> People goes "Yay I use Twitter too!"

I rarely hear laughter,
No matter what the day.

> You might hear laughter but mostly it's all typing with silence

Half of this is crucial,
The other not so much.

> People who use Twitter will found it crucial, while others not so much

This puzzle may be social,
Let's see who's super clutch.

> Again Open social media

Comment: Some good thoughts, but not quite. Good arguments for your point though. +1

Comment: Will some hints be available soon? =D

Comment: First hint just posted.

Answer (score 2):

It may be

> Luck

I make many feel like mice.

> Most people are unlucky

Some think I'm the open.

> I think this isn't the important part (half of this is crucial, the other not so much)

But sometimes I am nice

> No need to explain here, I guess

No need for doping

> Indeed, doping doesn't affect luck

You'll see what I am after

> You can't be lucky until you win!

Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"

> When you win...

I rarely hear laughter,
No matter what the day.

> Winners are few.

Half of this is crucial,
The other not so much.
This puzzle may be social,
Let's see who's super clutch.

> I don't think there's a hint here, just the half important thing.

Comment: I like the ideas, but not what I was going for. Hint 1 coming soon.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt (along with some thoughts):

> Needles

I make many feel like mice.

> Mice are experimented on, needles often make people feel the same.

Some think I'm the open.

> The phrasing here is odd. I'm guessing it's important but haven't figured out why yet. For this response, though, some see needles as opening up your veins.

But sometimes I am nice,
No need for doping.

> Needling someone is poking fun (but in a nice way) and another use for the word other than drugs

You'll see what I am after,
Maybe you'll even say "Yay!"

> When your blood is being drawn, you can see it. And you say "Yay!" because it's good that you have blood. :) A little weaker here.

I rarely hear laughter,
No matter what the day.

> Even if you are drawing blood, you're probably not laughing about it.

Half of this is crucial,
The other not so much.

> Here's a bit of wordplay. Half of it is "need" = "crucial". The other half is "not so much" i.e. it's "less".

This puzzle may be social,
Let's see who's super clutch.

> He's just putting this in because it's a tough puzzle and he's anticipating a community effort. Which he's got! Thought "super clutch" may be another important phrase here that I'm not catching.

Comment: Nice thoughts again. Missing a few things though, but great effort. Hint coming soon.